# Control not returning to UNIX when sqlplus is executed in while loop of shell script

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop, sqlplus

I have observed some of the shell scripts gets stuck because sqlplus session is not completing its session. This behavior is intermittent. I will give one of the scenario. Below is the code which executes one sql query.

```
 if [[ ${rcloop1} -eq 0 ]]; then
      sql_cnt_loop=0      
      # perform 2nd loop after 1 second to check if Indexing has completed
      sleep 1
      while : ; do
         exec_SQL "SELECT count(*)    \
                     FROM server_states  \
                    WHERE topic = 'WLM_FPFA_INDEXES'  \
                      AND current_state <> new_state \
                      AND server_name in ('${E_WLM_BATCH_SERVER_NAME_1}', '${E_WLM_BATCH_SERVER_NAME_2}')"
         rcloop2=$?

         if [[ $rcloop2 -eq 0 ]]; then
            sql_cnt_loop=$sql_cnt_loop+1
            if [[ ${E_WLM_SQL_RESULT} -eq 0 ]]; then
               Log "DJ Indexing has Completed..."
               rcloop2=0 # no rows - indexing has completed (not found in server_states table), return RC=0
               break     # exit from 2nd loop
            elif [[ ${E_WLM_SQL_RESULT} -gt 0 ]]; then
               sleep 1 # wait 1 sec then loop again
               continue  # record exists, continue monitoring indexing - loop again
            fi

         fi
      done

      rc=$rcloop2

   else
      rc=$rcloop1
   fi
```

below is the unix session.
pwlm 8297 8290 0 00:16 ? 00:00:03 /bin/ksh -a /opt/XWLMLL02
pwlm 29121 8297 0 00:32 ? 00:00:00 sqlplus -s

The script has run a process internally and above code part is to monitor whether the process is completed. Even though the process is completed, the script has not moved further from this point. Upon checking further, I have seen one active sqlplus session. I suspect that the sqlplus session is from the above code and it is somehow stuck in turn the script has stuck.

Below is the actual function exec_SQL.

```
exec_SQL()
{
   sql_Stmt=$1

   sql_Type=`echo $sql_Stmt | awk -F " " '{ printf toupper($1) }'`

   E_WLM_SQL_RESULT=`sqlplus -s /@${E_WLM_DB} <<!
      set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo on
      whenever SQLERROR exit SQL.SQLCODE
      whenever OSERROR exit 9
      $sql_Stmt;
      commit;
   !`

   sql_RC=$?

   if [[ $sql_RC -eq 0 ]]; then

      str_Result=`echo $E_WLM_SQL_RESULT | grep SP2`  

      if [[ ${#str_Result} > 0 ]]; then
         sql_RC=57      # SQL Error
         sql_Code=0 
      else
         export E_WLM_SQL_RESULT
      fi
   else
      sql_Code=$sql_RC   # Store SQL.SQLCODE before overwriting

      if [[ $sql_RC -eq 9 ]]; then   # OSERROR
         sql_RC=91     
      else
         case $sql_Type in 
            INSERT) sql_RC=52 ;;
            UPDATE) sql_RC=53 ;;
            SELECT) sql_RC=54 ;;
            DELETE) sql_RC=56 ;;
            *) sql_RC=57 ;;
         esac
      fi
   fi

   if [[ $sql_RC -ne 0 ]]; then
      Log "Error in executing SQL Statement: $sql_Stmt "
      Log "SQL.SQLCODE=$sql_Code"
      Log "=====================================   ORACLE ERROR DESCRIPTION  ====================================="  
      Log "$E_WLM_SQL_RESULT"
      Log "======================================================================================================="
      Log "Returning with $sql_RC"

   fi

   return $sql_RC 
}
```

I have observed this similar issue 3 times till now in the past 7 days. But, it is for different scripts. The logic remains the same.

This script was working fine in our old infrastructure where there was AIX server. We have not at all faced this issue over there.

Anyone, could help me to resolve the issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you really have the `!` line indented like that? The end tag of a here-doc has to be at the left margin.

Comment: yes. ! is present like that. I am unsure why the sqlplus gets stuck when all our scripts uses this generic function to execute sqlplus more than ten thousands time and only once it gets stuck.

Comment: You can also write `<<-!` and then you can indent the `!` line with TAB (not spaces). Maybe the other scripts are like that.

Comment: exec_SQL, It's a generic function. All the scripts call this function to execute the sql query.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you -- indenting the end token in a here-doc is not supposed to work.

Comment: But it should cause a shell syntax error, the script shouldn't hang.

Comment: ok. Thanks Barmar. It's very hard for me to get the cause of the issue. Because the same sqlplus code will work for thousands of queries and it stucks for a random query.